# SetOnClickListener and View view- Cannot resolve Symbol

Tags: java, android

I have already imported android.view.View on the java class but the code below still has SetOnClickListener and View view unresolved. Not sure if this is linked but I have used another onClick and View view method as observed in the second code.

```
    final ImageButton btnTest =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.passVisibilityStatus);
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void changePassVisibility (View view)
    btnTest.setSelected(!btnTest.isPressed());

    if (btnTest.isPressed()) {
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassVisible);
    } else {
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassInvisible);
    }
}}
```

Previous codes in case they are the problem:

```
public void loginButtonClicked(View view) {
    String email = loginEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass = loginPass.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    checkUserExists();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void checkUserExists() {
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You haven't overrided the onClick method in the anonymous onClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **override** the **OnClick** method in the OnClickListener.

Your new code should be:

```
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your desired code goes here.
    }
});
```

edit, **Solution**:

```
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        public void changePassVisibility (View view)
btnTest.setSelected(!btnTest.isPressed());

if (btnTest.isPressed()) {
    btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassVisible);
} else {
    btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassInvisible);
}
    }
});
```

Comment: An error "Annotations are not allowed here" pops up when I did that.

Comment: @JoshuaLee Please post your updated code and tells on which line you get this error.

Comment: `final ImageButton btnTest =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.passVisibilityStatus);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void changePassVisibility (View view)
        btnTest.setSelected(!btnTest.isPressed());

        if (btnTest.isPressed()) {
            btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassVisible);
        } else {
            btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassInvisible);
        }
    }}`

Comment: The exact line @Override on the above code has the error.

Comment: You did not follow my code in my answer. You need to override the OnClick method and put your code inside. I have edited my answer with new code

Comment: I did override the method and the error "Annotations are not allowed here" on the @Override pops up

Comment: You are missing the 'OnClick' line, please read carefully my edited answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read that. But the error still persists, the OnClick line would have an error "Variable OnClick is never used".

Comment: @JoshuaLee please post your code again, use pastebin this time

Comment: again, you are missing little things like semi cols. paste this code in your project. [link to code](https://pastebin.com/GQ1S1Pt4)

Comment: It still doesn't work, the last line ) has an error "Unexpected token" while the ; has '}' expected.

Comment: that's a 'silly' problem, check your code for { without closer ( } ). every { should have a }. and make sure you use my code .

Comment: Yes I did use your code, the problem still lies in the fact that onClick and View view method is unresolved.

Comment: @JoshuaLee maybe try to post your FULL file to pastebin so i can search for any problem that doesnt lie in this specific lines. because these lines look good

Comment: Here is the full code for the Java class the code is in: https://pastebin.com/yVKdE3H6

Comment: @JoshuaLee You are missing a } at the end of your code

Comment: Could it be that multiple methods that use the OnClickListener and View view result in only one of them being able to work?

Comment: I have found your problem, your chunk of code that we have talked about is just 'floating' in nowhere. get this code into the onCreate method. [solution](https://pastebin.com/7CUfQ1Bv)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onClick() method

```
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
//add this method
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // do something when the button is clicked
}
}
```

Comment: Same as the previous answer, an error "Annotations are not allowed here" pops up when I added @Override

Comment: @JoshuaLee are you use ButterKnife or any other similar libraries?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I also suspect that similar libraries might be the case

Comment: Then post your full java code then only you get solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the listener like this

```
final ImageButton btnTest =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.passVisibilityStatus);

       btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

        btnTest.setSelected(!btnTest.isPressed());

    if (btnTest.isPressed()) {
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassVisible);
    } else {
        btnTest.setImageResource(R.drawable.PassInvisible);
    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, the setOnClickListener and View view still remains unresolved and the ) at the last line has an 'unexpected token'.

Comment: @JoshuaLee You will have to post your full activity code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do as FlyingNades said, but I think your real problem is that you are not writing this code in his correct place, make sure your are calling "setOnClickListener" inside OnCreate() methode, this should resolve your issue.